Mysql8.0 a interesting scene of deadlock
Today we execute a java job,  and got a Exception about Mysql deadlock.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:124)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:354)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
    ... 25 more

At first ,we think it's a normal deadlock condition.
Finally,we found Deadlock may comes from select ... for update.
We use command show engine innodb status to show deadlock information, like this:

=====================================
2024-12-27 02:51:05 140067749193472 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 11 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 655234 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 5905739 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2518134
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1539007
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 0.00 RW-shared, 0.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2024-12-27 02:24:16 140068337477376
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3165095, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 13899, OS thread handle 140066175198976, query id 19098873 192.168.10.195 root update
INSERT INTO `daily_statistic_data_2021`
            (`imei`,`last_calculate_time`,`year`,`month`,`day`,`di1`,`di2`,`di3`,`di4`,`di5`,`di6`,`di7`,`di8`,`do1`,`do2`,`do3`,`do4`,`do5`,`do6`,`do7`,`do8`)
        values ('861213052219265','2021-09-01 17:57:07','2021','09','01',0.0,0.0,0.0,13000.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 376 page no 5 n bits 72 index daily_statistic_data_unique of table `es`.`daily_statistic_data_2021` trx id 3165095 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 15; hex 383633383636303439373932383135; asc 863866049792815;;
 1: len 4; hex 32303231; asc 2021;;
 2: len 2; hex 3038; asc 08;;
 3: len 2; hex 3235; asc 25;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 376 page no 5 n bits 72 index daily_statistic_data_unique of table `es`.`daily_statistic_data_2021` trx id 3165095 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 15; hex 383633383636303439373932383135; asc 863866049792815;;
 1: len 4; hex 32303231; asc 2021;;
 2: len 2; hex 3038; asc 08;;
 3: len 2; hex 3235; asc 25;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3165096, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 13904, OS thread handle 140066184709888, query id 19098879 192.168.10.193 root update
INSERT INTO `daily_statistic_data_2021`
            (`imei`,`last_calculate_time`,`year`,`month`,`day`,`di1`,`di2`,`di3`,`di4`,`di5`,`di6`,`di7`,`di8`,`do1`,`do2`,`do3`,`do4`,`do5`,`do6`,`do7`,`do8`)
        values ('861213050685368','2021-09-01 21:56:28','2021','09','01',0.0,0.0,0.0,19000.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 376 page no 5 n bits 72 index daily_statistic_data_unique of table `es`.`daily_statistic_data_2021` trx id 3165096 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 15; hex 383633383636303439373932383135; asc 863866049792815;;
 1: len 4; hex 32303231; asc 2021;;
 2: len 2; hex 3038; asc 08;;
 3: len 2; hex 3235; asc 25;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 376 page no 5 n bits 72 index daily_statistic_data_unique of table `es`.`daily_statistic_data_2021` trx id 3165096 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 15; hex 383633383636303439373932383135; asc 863866049792815;;
 1: len 4; hex 32303231; asc 2021;;
 2: len 2; hex 3038; asc 08;;
 3: len 2; hex 3235; asc 25;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 3179361
Purge done for trx's n:o < 3179361 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 40
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421543863828424, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863827616, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863823576, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863824384, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863826808, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863826000, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863825192, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863822768, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421543863821960, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)

// ignore IO information


Interesting is that:  trx 3165095 waiting for lock from itself! How?
logic of Java job is that:
   1. select ... for update;
   2. if(!exist)
        insert a new record;
      else
        update record;
   3. commit;

Normally, Session-1 execute select ... where condition=1 for update (without release it) , then  Session-2 execute select ... where condition=1 for update will waiting lock until timeout(without using SKIP LOCKED).
But fact is not. we test show that: If table is empty. Session-1 and Session-2  execute select ... for update will retrun immediately :

Then we execute insert operation will get a Deadlock(Session-1 success,Session-2 fail),even lock different records :

If table is not empty ,it works well (normal-appearing):

May be implementation of select...for update semantics is different between table is empty or not. And we can't found correlative information from mysql Documentation-locking reads

Does your real deadlock happen when the table is empty as well? Why don't you use insert on ... on duplicate key update .... instead of select for update - if exists insert else update logic?

yes, It's real deadlock , after session-1,session-2 return from select ... for update.  If only session-1 execute insert operation , session-1 will be blocked (waiting session-2 to release lock). Then, session-2 execute insert operation cause deadlock.

But does that deadlock happen when the table is empty as in your experiment?

yes. it deadlock happen in my experiment.

Why don't you use insert on ... on duplicate key update  good plan!  If i only modify mysql state ，i will use it.  Using for update  make behind java statement Atomic, i ignore them.

Now we use try-catch the  MySQLTransactionRollbackException , and using retry to solve it
